# Customise number of links shown in Laravel pagination on query results

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, nuxt.js, laravel-pagination

I'm using Laravel's [Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination) feature on my query in my application that's returned as a JSON response back to my front-end *(it's a Laravel Rest API)*

```php
/**
 * Applications
 */
public function getApplications()
{

    $applications = Application::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                               ->paginate(25);

    foreach ($applications as $key => $applicant) {
      try {
        $applications[$key]['data'] = json_decode($applicant['data']);
      } catch (\Exception $e) { }
    }

    return $applications;

}

/**
 * All applications
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 */
public function applications(Request $request)
{

    try {

      // daily graphs
      $applications = $this->getApplications();

      // not set or nothing to report
      if (!$applications) {
        return response()->json([
          'success' => false,
          'msg' => 'No applications found, check back in a few minutes',
        ], 422);
      }

      // return the response
      return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'msg' => 'Icicle applications',
        'applications' => $applications ?? null
      ], 200);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

      // return default template
      return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'msg' => 'We were unable to load applications right now',
      ], 422);

    }

}
```

However, the default number of links shown on the page start at 1, and proceed to 10 which is too many for me and I'd like to reduce them down to show fewer links, for example, 1 through to 5.

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to configure the paginator here, and since it's not a view, how can I reduce the links down? Am I missing some configuration?

[image: pagination example]

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/pagination#adjusting-the-pagination-link-window) suggests doing this inside your blade template:

```
{{ $users->onEachSide(5)->links() }}
```

---

If you do [client-side templating](https://laravel.com/docs/frontend#using-vue-react) instead, you can use this:

```
/**
 * Applications
 */
public function getApplications()
{

    $paginator = Application::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                               ->paginate(25);

    return array_merge($paginator, [
        'pages' => $paginator->getUrlRange(1, 10)
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Okay, however, as mentioned, it's a "Laravel Rest API", so the data is sent to my front-end, which is built in Nuxt JS and uses axios to make requests between the front-end and back-end, so there's no blade files.

Comment: Oh, would you mind adding the NuxtJS tag to your question to emphasize this?

Comment: Maybe you can use ` $model->paginate()->getUrlRange()`

Comment: `getUrlRange` literatly returns an array of 10 items with `getUrlRange(1, 10)` and none of the other pieces of data, such as first page, and more importantly, my data from my db.

Comment: You probably have to do `$paginator = $model->paginate(); array_merge($paginator, [ 'pages' => $paginator->getUrlRange(1, 10) ]);`

Comment: are you able to attach a code example fleshed out a bit more with my actual model and query? Note the `getApplications` function has the `Application` model, rather than `$model`

Comment: Sure. See above.